# Javascript Array get offset-index from specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

can anyone suggest a snippet or a short method to solve this:

```
array = [a,b,c,d,e,f]

currentIndex = 2;

getOffset(array,currentIndex,2); // 2+2 = 4 -> return 'e'

getOffset(array,currentIndex,-2); // -> return 'a'

getOffset(array,currentIndex,-3); // -> return 'f'

getOffset(array,currentIndex,-4); // -> return 'e'

getOffset(array,currentIndex, 5); // -> return 'b'
```

So if the the targetted index is bigger than array.length or < 0 -> simulate a circle loop inside the array and continue to step inside the indexes.

Can anyone help me?
I tried, but got a buggy script :(

TY!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
function getOffset(arr,index, offset){   
    return arr[(arr.length+index+(offset%arr.length))%arr.length];
}
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for the reason described here: http://javascript.about.com/od/problemsolving/a/modulobug.htm The double modulo/dividend is necessary. Nice answer Amber.

Comment: Yep. But `getOffset(arr,2,-9)` would return `undefined`

Comment: Did you use `array = [a, b, c, d, e, f]` to test it? Then it obviously returns `undefined` because there are no values defined for the variable `a` to `f`

Comment: @Amberlamps: I stand corrected, and no, I tested with ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"], but switched offset/index.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick, I suppose:

```
function getOffset(arr,n,offset) {
   offset = offset || 0;
   var raw = (offset+n)%arr.length;
   return raw < 0 ? arr[arr.length-Math.abs(raw)] : arr[raw];
}

var arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
getOffset(arr,-3,2); //=> 'f'
getOffset(arr,-3);   //=> 'd'
//but also ;~)
getOffset(arr,-56,2);  //=> 'a'
getOffset(arr,1024,2); //=> 'a'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulus operator:

```
function getOffset(arr, index, step) {
  return arr[(((index + step) % arr.length) + arr.length) % arr.length];
}
```

Comment: When |offset| is > index it will result in a negative index!

Comment: @Amberlamps, bvukelic: What when index is 1 and step is -5? Modulus, IMO, isn't defined for negative numbers. I did the downvote.

Comment: `%` in JavaScript actually returns the dividend. If we want to only allow positive index's we could get the `abs` but I'm not sure that's the intended functionality, or necessary.